# 'MKCoordinateRegionMake' is unavailable in Swift

Tags: swift, mapkit, swift5

I am migrating from swift 3 to swift 5.1, I get this error

> 'MKCoordinateRegionMake' is unavailable in Swift

Answer (score 0):

Those kind of Objective-C like constructors have been removed from Swift and their equivalent is:

```swift
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, latitudinalMeters: latitudinalMeters, longitudinalMeters:longitudinalMeters)
```

There are other initializers as well and you can find them in the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcoordinateregion